# How to redirect user and display his/her username to a different page in Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to redirect the user (who has successfully logged in) to an article page with his/her username. but for some reason i don't see the username of the user in the article page.

article html:

```
<div class="container post" >
    <h2 class="author"><a>{{ username }}</a></h2>
    <hr>
    <h6 class="subject"> </h6>
    <p class="comment"><br><br>
</div>
```

**article view:**

```
def article(request):
    template = 'librarysystem/article.html'
    return render(request, template)
```

Ajax:

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/librarysystem/Login/",
    data: {
      'username':$("#loginUsername").val(),
      'password':$("#loginPassword").val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:$
      ('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val
      ()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      if (data.response){
        initalizeForm();
        $("#invalid").html(" ");
        $('#loginmodal').modal('hide'); 
        console.log(data.username);
        window.location = data.redirectTo + "?username=" + data.username;
      }else
      $("#invalid").html("<h5> Invalid username or password. </h5>").css('color','red');
    },                                        
    error: function(jqXHR, status, err){
      alert(jqXHR.responseText);                                    
    }
  });                           
});
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$',views.registerUser),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="Index"),
    url(r'^validateRegisterForm/$',views.validateRegisterForm),
    url(r'^validateLoginForm/$',views.validateLoginForm),
    url(r'^article/$', views.article, name="Article"),
    url(r'^Login/$',views.loginUser, name="Login"),
    url(r'^Logout/$',views.logoutUser, name="Logout"),
]
```

views.py:

```
def loginUser(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
       username = request.POST.get('username')
       password = request.POST.get('password')
       user = authenticate(username=username,password=password);        
       if user is None:
            data['response'] = False
       else:
            login(request,user)
            data['response'] = True
            data['redirectTo'] = "/librarysystem/article/"
            data['username'] = username         
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Please include the `article` view

Comment: @Sayse I edited the question with article view see

Comment: you can get it by {{request.user.get_full_name}}

Comment: also please send us print of this {{request.user}} and {{request}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is an Ajax response and you are passing the string as a query string to the url you won't be able to use the username directly in the template. You can either get the variable of query string with `{{request.get.username}}`. or As the user is logged  in we can access the user object directly in the view when you render your template with `render(request, '<template_name>')`
in your template you can access username as following

```
{{user.username}} or {{request.user.username}}
```

It is better to user `{% if user.is_athenticated %}` condition before using {{user.username}} that checks if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Like so :  {% if user.is_authenticated() %}
             <button type="button" value="Logout" id="logout"></button>             
          <a style="float: right;" class="nav-link" href="#">{{ request.user.username }}</a>

Comment: @Ahti Are you getting any exception?

Comment: @Ahti You are missing {% endif %}. We used if condition, so this should be closed with {% endif %}, so change your code to 
{% if user.is_authenticated %} <button type="button" value="Logout" id="logout"></button> <a style="float: right;" class="nav-link" href="#">{{ request.user.username }}</a>{% endif %}

Comment: but this is python so there is no 'endif' according to python syntax. its in vb

Comment: Yeah but we wrote this in our template. Django template language requires {% endif %}. For more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-if

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more than likely the fact that you don't reference the `username` from the `request.GET` dictionary in the context of your `article` view.

But even if you did this it is potentially error prone and insecure since anyone can just put any username they want into this get parameter.

Instead, just forget about the get parameter and [get the username](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username) from the `request`'s `user` object.

```
<h2 class="author"><a>{{ request.user.get_username }}</a></h2>
```

---

Your article view confirms the issue

```
def article(request):
    template = 'librarysystem/article.html'
    return render(request, template, {'username': request.GET.get('username')})
```

Comment: okay, how should i display a logout button right in side of username which when clicked should logout the user ?

Comment: @Ahti - That is a different question for which you should raise a new question complete with what you have tried and researched.

Comment: okay by including "return render(request, template, {'username': request.GET.get('username')})" then should i not include "window.location = data.redirectTo + "?username=" + data.username;" right ?

Comment: @Ahti - No, you don't need to include the `username` in the context at all (nor in the jquery), Just reference it from the request object as shown

Comment: why doesn't this work: {% if user.is_authenticated %}
             <button type="button" value="Logout" id="logout"></button>             
             <a style="float: right;" class="nav-link" href="#">{{ request.user.username }}</a> ??

Comment: @Ahti - That is MicroPyramid's answer so maybe better to ask them why it doesn't work. Otherwise, again that is a different question.

Comment: this is not a different question its related to current one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134959/discussion-between-ahti-and-sayse).